# Finding exact Fonttype in pure Java based on a Android FontType

Tags: java, android, fonts

I need to measure the size of a text in a specific Font in Android and in pure Java and it needs to be the exact same size. I know how to measure fontsizes in general in Android and in Java, but I have realized, that the measures are different.

Code to show the problem:

in Android I get a size of 35.0 / 10.0

```
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds("L y d i a n", 0, sText.length(), bounds);
    float textwidth = bounds.width();   //35.0
    float textheight = bounds.height(); //10.0
```

In pure Java I get a size of 34.0 / 10.0

```
float textwidth = getTextWidth("L y d i a n", (int)fTextSize, "Sans");      //34.0
float textheight = getTextHeight("L y d i a n", (int)fTextSize, "Sans");    //10.0


public float getTextWidth(String text, int FontSize, String Fonttype){
    AffineTransform affinetransform = new AffineTransform();     
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(affinetransform,true,true);     
    Font font = new Font(Fonttype, Font.PLAIN, FontSize);
    int textwidth = (int)(font.getStringBounds(text, frc).getWidth());
    return textwidth;
}
```

I am testing the Android Code Snippet on a Tablet and the JAVA AWT Snippet Code on my Computer.

I am sure I am not handling with the same font, but I can't see the Problem. Is "sans" in Java the same as SANS_SERIF in Android ? I hope someone sees the reason for the measure difference.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Android *is* Java, so the basic concept if you need the same result is "use the same code"... as such I don't quite understand your question, is there some reason you can't use the pure Java code? And with that said, the fact that you get pure, clean integer values instead of fractional decimals is extremely suspect: they're probably *both* doing the wrong thing, and being off by 1 suggests they simply round differently.

Comment: Thanks, but its not a rounding problem. "Android is Java" of course I know, but how would I explain this issue without using terms Android and pure Java. If you would copy the code for both OS you would see the problem.... I need exact the same result for the same Fonts. But obviously Android-OS JVM renders the same Font different then a "pure Java" JVM.

Comment: that would be the difference between either the JVMSL "Java" and "Dalvik", or the APIs, in which case it's "Android" and "Java AWT" (at least in this case, since you're using the awt Font classes). And that difference is important, because it lets you rule something out. Also important is saying what you're testing each snippet on. Are you testing on the same device (if so, phone, or AVD on a computer?), or on phone/computer separately?

Comment: I am testing the Android Code Snippet on a Tablet and the JAVA AWT Snippet Code on my Computer. I updated the Question to be more precise. Thanks !

Comment: Nice. Also a good idea to be explicit about the versions here. Android has a lot of versions and a lot of SDK versions so saying which Android the tablet is running (version + build) and which SDK version you used to compile it, as well as noting which version of Java you're on (JRE and JDK versions probably) will help others who might have run into this before determine whether their past situation applies to your current one. Also, have you tried running the plain Java code on the tablet? Does that agree with the Android code values or the Desktop java values?